# Fast Zoom Effect to New Camera

Tags: effects

So I'm trying to recreate an effect that was used quite a bit in the first Hulk movie. I've seen it other places, but Hulk sticks in my mind.

So the concept is that there are two cameras, one recording a relatively wide angle, capturing two subjects and a bit of background, and another camera recording a closer crop of one subject.

[image: Diagram]

This is a common setup, but what I'm focusing on is the transition between these two cameras. Normally, something as simple as a dissolve is used, but I've also seen a transition which looks like a fast zoom, but is actually a transition. This is what I'd like to know how to do.

If I can find an example, I'll edit this post. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- On the outgoing footage add a qucick zoom at the end, on the incoming
  footage add a quick zoom at the beginning (animate the scale of the
  clips using whatever tools your NLE has for this). If the outgoing
  zoom is a zoom in, then zoom out, and vice-versa.
- Add a dissolve between the two clips that is the same length as the
  zoom. The whole thing needs to be very quick, 12 frames or so tops.
- A radial blur can help as well to simulate motion blur.

I wrote a FCP (version 7 or lower) plugin that did this as a transition effect. I can dig it out if you want it.